# Problemw with io.restassured which ignored restcontrolleradvice

Tags: java, spring-boot, kotlin, rest-assured

I have a problem with io.restassured, its ignore the rest controller advice, and returns 500. In rest controller advice, i map this runtime exceptions to 400, any solution?